# Does updating a row cause a delete trigger to fire?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger on insert, delete or update. In SQL Server 2014, by default, does an update query cause a table's delete trigger to be executed?

Comment: No, it will only trigger the update trigger

Comment: I can't answer for SQL Server, but I would expect that the answer is "no" — a DELETE triggers a delete trigger, not an UPDATE.

Comment: is it possible to call trigger recursively when recursive trigger option is disabled

Comment: @MarcusHöglund you should post this as answer probably instead of comment as this is the answer to the question (by the way, instead of "update trigger" which is not some we have you should use "DML Trigger" on "UPDATE event" ;-)

Comment: @RonenAriely Thanks! did add an answer:) please edit it if you feel

Comment: Do you have an insert,update,delete trigger - if so then it will fire on any of these data modifications.

Comment: `True P.Salmon`, but the answer to he question "`does an update query cause a table's delete trigger to be executed?`" is "`no`". The Trigger on insert,update, and delete will be fired, since this is a trigger on Delete event as well (The DELETE event is what trigger the fire not the UPDATE) - just to clarify if this is not clear to someone why the answer is no while  P.Salmon is right and this trigger will be fired.

Comment: See for the testing purpose what I had done, created a trigger (AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on a table also I had created one temp table for storing deleted and inserted count against the table. when I delete any row in the table then my temp table shows deleted count = 1 and when I update any row in the table it shows inserted count = 1 and deleted count = 1

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it will only trigger the update trigger i.e *the DML Trigger on UPDATE event* (Cred to Ronen Ariely)

Answer (score -1):

There is such

> No

implicit triggers for delete .